# How to query a staging database?

Tags: php, database, query, staging

I have a staging site set up, which works just fine.   I need to run a query from my page against one of the CF7DB  tables (to check for duplicate entry).   The query works great against the production cf7db table.  However, when I am in the production site, the query still runs against the production table.

Here is my query (works against production):
`$query = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT count(*) FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits WHERE form_name = %s AND field_name = %s AND field_value = %s", 'Hike_Sign_Up_Form','hike_hiker_key',$querystring);`

I tried changing the connection of the default db to my staging db, and it appears that worked.  This prints out the name of the staging db.

`$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "defaultdb");
mysqli_select_db($link, "stagingdb");
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT DATABASE()")) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
    mysqli_free_result($result);  }`

However, if I then run the below query, it still pulls against the production db.
`$query = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT count(*) FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits WHERE form_name = %s AND field_name = %s AND field_value = %s", 'Hike_Sign_Up_Form','hike_hiker_key',$querystring);`

I've been through php documentation, spent over an hour with the hosting company support - who finally told me that I can't run queries against a staging db, only against the production.   hmm...   seems wrong to me.   Anyway - I'm stuck at this point, and would appreciate any pointers you folks have.   Thanks!

Comment: I don't know where you host, but I know for a fact that on SiteGround, when you create a staging site, queries there go against the staging db. The name changes required are automatic.

Comment: I am at eHost.  What you  mention, John, makes sense to me.  Thus, my question to the group.   Something seems amis.